# Android : instumentation testing for app widgets

Tags: android, testing, junit, android-appwidget

I am looking to automate testing for home-screen widgets. I have looked at [android testing page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/testing/testing_android.html), and the [InstrumentationTestRunner class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/InstrumentationTestRunner.html). I have also looked at CTS source code; but I have not been able to find anything useful.

The closest I could find was this [Robolectric ShadowAppWidgetManager](http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/javadoc/com/xtremelabs/robolectric/shadows/ShadowAppWidgetManager.html), but I am not sure how I would use it.

Could you please share how you test the app widgets? Is there any framework or library that I can utilize?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe a good way is to make a separate test project that tests out the functionality of your widget and reports test/fails in a file that later you can "adb pull".

Compilation can be done via command line & automation via ant. Also you can launch and android simulator via command line too an use adb to install the apk, run the app, and get results via command line. A lot of work I agree. The nice thing is the testing part code wise is independent of being in a simulator and very easily adapted to install on a real device.